# View/Change Initial Catalog in DBConnection

Tags: c#, dbconnection

1. If I create `DBConnection` specifying an `Initial Catalog`, once the object is created, how can I get the name of that database?  It seems that `DBConnection.Database` seems to just return `master`.
2. If I use `DBConnection.ChangeDatabase()`, does that mean that I can write queries against this database directly without specifying the database name (i.e., as if it was the `Initial Catalog`)?

Comment: SQL connects you to `master` by default, so it is logical that that is returned. What table's name are you attempting to retrieve?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `database`.  I want to get back the name of the `Initial Catalog`.  It seems to me that should be the default setting of the `Database` property, not `master`.

Comment: What problem you are trying to solve? Why you need to configure one initial catalog and then replace it with other initial catalog?

Comment: I am using the Microsoft `DataConnectionDialogue` (as here https://www.nuget.org/packages/DataConnectionDialog/).  I want to be able to prepopulate a "selected database" dropdown with the initial catalog if one was selected.

Comment: I don't necessarily want to change the initial catalog, i just want to change the default database so I don't have to specify this in the query.  I would think that would be specified by `DbConnection.Database`, but it seems it is not.

Comment: Why don't you connect to `master` then, retrieve the list of databases from the system table and then perform a `ChangeDatabase` with the name of the one you're looking for?

Comment: That's the problem, I don't know which `Initial Catalog` the user selected.  In other words, there has got to be a better way to determine this than trying to parse the Connection String.

Comment: @dashnick Totally agree on not trying to parse the connectionstring yourself. Use the [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) class with the string as the parameter. It parses it for you and you can retrieve the `InitialCatalog` property of the object.

Comment: Thank you, didn't realize you could do that! Perfect solution.  Still don't understand why `DBConnection.Database` is set to `master` if you specify an initial catalog.  Wouldn't this mean that the default database would be `master` if you ran a query without specifying the database?